# Bundles based on CDN not rendering script tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cdn, bundling-and-minification

I have bundles set up based on CDN:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.UseCdn = true;

        AddCss(bundles);
        AddJavaScript(bundles);
    }

private static void AddJavaScript(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        Bundle fastFontsBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/fastfont", ContentDeliveryNetwork.FastFont.FastFontCdn)
            .Include("~/Scripts/232e7a0d-2062-499d-ae27-5c6985d43bef.js");
        bundles.Add(fastFontsBundle);
    }

public static class ContentDeliveryNetwork
{
    public static class FastFont
    {
        public const string Domain = "fast.fonts.net";
        public const string FastFontCdn = "//fast.fonts.net/jsapi/232e7a0d-2062-499d-ae27-5c6985d43bef.js";
    }
}
```

I run in debug mode so each script should get rendered as a script tag. But it does not. Scripts that are stored locally work. The jquery CDN works. But this custom one I made does not work. Its not rendering the script tag, so I don't even get a 404 or other error.

Comment: Have you added this bundle to your view?

Comment: Its added to the _Layout. @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fastfont"). Other bundles, that just get files locally work fine

Comment: @EthanSchofer Try adding a trailing slash in both your view and when declaring `fastFontsBundle`